# Angularjs filter not working with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

Angularjs filter not working with ng-repeat when I change filter value with a function... I am new to angularjs.

These are my html buttons from which the filter value must be changed with the function on 'ng-click';

```
<span>
    <a class="button button-stable" ng-class="class('static')"
       ng-click="activate('static','','')">
        All
    </a>
</span>
<span ng-repeat="profiles in cardList | unique:'profile'">
    <a class="button button-stable" ng-class="class($index)"
       ng-click="activate($index,profiles,profiles.profile);">
        {{profiles.profile}}
    </a>
</span>
```

These are my controller functions;

```
$scope.cardList = [
    {id: 1, serial_number: '35986580', card_number: 'BG9S8W7DJSKLA9', profile: '512', expiry_date: '5-1-2017'},
    {id: 2, serial_number: '35986581', card_number: 'ASLWODS6F5812H', profile: '512', expiry_date: '5-1-2017'},
    {id: 3, serial_number: '35986582', card_number: '9A5S218LSKJBMC', profile: '768', expiry_date: '5-1-2017'},
    {id: 4, serial_number: '35986583', card_number: 'XLCKDIGOSJS092', profile: '1024', expiry_date: '5-1-2017'},
    {id: 5, serial_number: '35986584', card_number: 'XKSODKO0CNJSUW', profile: '1024', expiry_date: '5-1-2017'},
    {id: 6, serial_number: '35986585', card_number: 'PLHG0G9M746172', profile: '2048', expiry_date: '5-1-2017'},
    {id: 7, serial_number: '35986586', card_number: '5DF888F9EGVNDJ', profile: '2048', expiry_date: '5-1-2017'},
    {id: 8, serial_number: '35986587', card_number: 'D6F5G49ILMA9SF', profile: '4096', expiry_date: '5-1-2017'}
];
$scope.class = function(index, item){
    if ($scope.selected == index){
        return 'button-dark active';
    } else {
        $scope.staticAll = '';
        return '';
    }
}
$scope.activate = function(index, item, profile){
    if (index != 'static'){
        $scope.selected = index;
        $scope.filterProfile = profile;
        $scope.staticAll = '';
    } else {
        $scope.selected = 'static';
        $scope.filterProfile = '';
        $scope.staticAll = 'button-dark active';
    }
}
```

And this is where the filter is not working;

```
<tr ng-repeat="card in cardList | filter: filterProfile">
                <td class="center">{{card.profile}}</td>
                <td class="center">{{card.expiry_date}}</td>
                <td class="center"><a class="button button-medium button-energized">Assign</a></td>
            </tr>
```

This is an image;

[image: screenshot]

I want to filter the results with profile buttons, but the value of 'filterProfile' is not changing...

Please help...

Comment: This seems to work fine [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/jYHgkPGIcI7Hv7qWCOHl?p=preview) (Obviously not stylized the same).

Comment: Yup I accidentally ended the ng-controller div before the table.
`<div ng-controller="cardscontroller">..lots..of..html...</div><table><tr ng-repeat='card in cardList | filter: filterProfile'>.....card-details...</tr></table>`
Thanks anyway sir...

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is take a model to its filter option, I imagine that the divs with those numbers in particular.

Now I do not quite understand as a weapon profiles wishlist but, in their profiles, you must give ng-model such as `ng-model = "profileSelected"`

And to your list, add

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="card in cardList | filter: profileSelected">
```

for better help, you can create a codepen?

Comment: Thanks. This was the problem;
`<div ng-controller="cardsController">....html...</div><table><tr></tr><tr ng-repeat="card in cardList | filter: filterProfile">
                <td class="center">{{card.profile}}</td>
                <td class="center">{{card.expiry_date}}</td>
                <td class="center"><a class="button button-medium button-energized">Assign</a></td>
</tr></table></div>`

I accidentally ended the <div> tag.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not so clear what you want for an end product, but I can tell you that's not how custom filters are defined. the format is something like

```
    var app = angular.module('buttonApp',[]);
    app.filter('myFilter', function() {
    return function(x) {
        //filter goodness in here
      }    
    })
```

You can find the official documentation for filters here https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_11

Comment: Where exactly is OP defining any sort of custom filter?